# Invalid topic name while calling watch() from c#

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a topic with all permission and subscription. from google cloud console I can list my topics. BUT from c# code, or TRY IT page am getting invalid topic name. I have created a project
enabled pub/sub api
create topic
created subscription
granted permission
created api keys
am getting unread messages from gmail, that means the key is working fine. but cant get topic name
here is my code:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1;
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
class Program
{
    static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly };
    static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret2.json", FileMode.Open, 
FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/gmail-dotnet-
quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
     //UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = 
service.Users.Labels.List("me");

        List<Message> result = new List<Message>();
        UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest request = 
service.Users.Messages.List("me");
        request.Q = "is:unread";

        do
        {
            try
            {
                ListMessagesResponse response = request.Execute();
                result.AddRange(response.Messages);
                request.PageToken = response.NextPageToken;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            }
        } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
        foreach (Message m in result)
        {
            Message m2 = service.Users.Messages.Get("me", m.Id).Execute();
            Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", m2.Snippet);
        }

        WatchRequest body = new WatchRequest()
        {
            TopicName = "projects/test/topics/topicTest",
            LabelIds = new[] { "INBOX" }
        };
  string userId = "me";
        UsersResource.WatchRequest watchRequest = service.Users.Watch(body, 
userId);
        WatchResponse test = watchRequest.Execute();
        Console.Read();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me where the Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 library comes in here - it looks like you're currently just using the GMail API. If you're seeing a problem in the PubSub API, could you show the code there?